# Bearer Token Auth makes my API didn't work (Node Js)

Tags: node.js, authorization, bearer-token

So I used Bearer Token auth for my stack, I tested all the api on post, put and delete certain elements for admin privilages. It worked perfectly but when I include `isAuth` which is the function of my middleware it is pending for a long time and said cant reach the server.
This is my `isAuth` Code. I've been try to debug for days but avail to no result.

```
const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  if (token) {
    const onlyToken = token.slice(7, token.length);
    jwt.verify(onlyToken, config.JWT_SECRET, (err, decode) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Invalid Token' });
      }
      req.user = decode;
      console.log(decode)
      next();
      return
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Token is not supplied." });
  }
}
```

Below is my API Post Code where it works if i dont include isAuth param inside.

```js
router.post("/", isAuth, async(req, res) => {
  const tutor = new Tutor({
    name: req.body.name,
    image: req.body.image,
    banner: req.body.banner,
    class1: req.body.class1,
    class2: req.body.class2,
    studentCount: req.body.studentCount,
    major: req.body.major,
    university: req.body.university,
    price: req.body.price,
    bundlePrice: req.body.bundlePrice,
    description: req.body.description,
    linkedIn: req.body.linkedIn,
    video: req.body.video,
    schedule: req.body.schedule,
  });
  const newTutor = await tutor.save();
  if(newTutor){
    return res.status(201).send({message: "New Tutor Registered", data: newTutor });
  }
  return res.status(500).send({message: "Error in Registering Tutor"})
})
```

if I include the param `isAuth` like above then it would be like this:

[image: XHR Pending until about 2 minutes]

[image: XHR Failed (net: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)]

If I don't include `isAuth` then it would perfectly works like this
[image: XHR Completed]

Comment: Can you please explain your issue a liitle more,by providing some more code/screenshots.

Comment: Oh wait, im gonna screenshot how it didn't work